# Django find in joined set

Tags: django, django-models

When i have, say, a Datamodel named "Computer", and there are many Users for many Computers, I create a manytomany-relationship between "Computer" and "User".
Now I want to select any Computer that is used by User 1. I tried this:

```
computers = Computer.objects.filter(users__contains=1)
```

But this does not seem to work since the __contains-operator acts as "like". What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the __contains so you get.

```
computers = Computer.objects.filter(users=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's as simple as:

```
computers = Computer.objects.filter(user__id=1)
```